# Auto Ec2 stop after aws member logoff

Tags: amazon-ec2, auto

Is there a way that Amazon Web Services EC2 instances can be self stoping ? Does Amazon have anything that allows an instance to stop itself ("Hara-Kiri") after aws member user logoff from the console.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add more details? For example, is this Linux or Windows? What do you mean by "user logoff from the console"? Do you mean, for example, that they are using RDP to connect to a Windows instance and they are disconnecting from the RDP session? Please tell us more about your particular use-case so that we can provide an appropriate recommendation.

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to fulfill? Why do you want to turn off the user is finished with it (i.e. whats the server role)?

Comment: We have more than  50 membsers of my root account. They are creating instances & perform the operation. Instances may be Windows, Linux & RDS. Now i want these running Ec2 & RDS instances automatically stop when member user logoff from the aws Console.

Comment: There is no concept of "logoff" on Amazon RDS database instances. Also, presumably, you do not wish to turn off databases that are a shared resource.

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty with this is defining *when* to stop the instance. Amazon EC2 provides the virtual hardware, but it cannot 'see' what the Operating System is doing.

You could, for example, create an Amazon CloudWatch alarm based on CPU level, and stop the instance if CPU Utilization is below a certain level for a period of time, but even this isn't guaranteed to indicate that a user has logged-off.

The best option would for the user to select "Shutdown" when they are finished with the instance. Amazon EC2 will then Stop the instance and it can be Started later.

Comment: Thanks for your kind input, but as per the our requirement, Ec2 instance should be automatically Stop,as member user log off

Comment: Would this be for an Amazon EC2 instance running **Windows**? A quick web search indicates that you can [configure scripts to run when a user logsoff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789190(v=ws.11)). This script would simply need to call a PowerShell command that does a shutdown of the computer. This would cause EC2 to Stop the instance after shutdown.

Comment: Hello John, this can be done for one instance, but we have more than 100 instances that are running by different member users. How can i set this script for the root account.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "root account", but this configuration could be installed in the instances when they first boot (via a User Data script), or you can run a command on all 100 instances using the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) (if each instance has the Agent installed and an appropriate role assigned). Please note that the concept of a user logging off is totally based on the operating system, not the EC2 management system, so that's why it needs to be configured on each computer.